# Calculate $\iint_D x dxdy$ using polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Using polar coordinates, I want to calculate $\iint_D x dxdy$, where $D$ is the disk with center $(2,3)$ and radius $2$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

We have $D=\{(x,y)\mid (x-2)^2+(y-3)^2\leq 4\}$.

We use $(x,y)=(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)$.

From the inequality $$(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2\leq 4\Rightarrow x^2-4x+4+y^2-6y+9\leq 4 \Rightarrow x^2+y^2-4x-6y\leq -9$$ we get $$r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta-4r\cos\theta-6r\sin\theta\leq -9 \Rightarrow r^2-r(4\cos\theta-6\sin\theta)+9\leq 0$$ 
To find for which values of $r$ that inequality is true, we have to find first the roots of $r^2-r(4\cos\theta-6\sin\theta)+9=0$.

The roots are $$2\cos \theta+3\sin\theta\pm \sqrt{12\cos\theta\sin\theta-5\cos^2\theta}$$ Therefore, we get the inequality $r^2-r(4\cos\theta-6\sin\theta)+9\leq 0$ for $$2\cos \theta+3\sin\theta-\sqrt{12\cos\theta\sin\theta-5\cos^2\theta}\leq r\\  \leq 2\cos \theta+3\sin\theta+\sqrt{12\cos\theta\sin\theta-5\cos^2\theta}$$ or not?

So, at the integral do we use these limits for $r$ ? And what about $\theta$ ? Does it hold that $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$ ?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Use substitution
\begin{cases}
x=2+r\cos\theta,\\
y=3+r\sin\theta,\\
\end{cases}
then
$$\iint_D xdxdy=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2r(2+r\cos\theta)\,dr\,d\theta$$

Comment: By using the substitution $x=2+r\cos\theta,\ y=3+r\sin\theta$ do we shift the circle so that its center is in origin?

Comment: Mainly we can shift our coordinates $(x,y)$ to new coordinates $(X,Y)$ with substitution $X=x+\alpha$, $Y=y+\beta$ then all functions and points goes to new coordinates. Here let $X=x-2$ and $Y=y-3$, so your integral will be $\displaystyle\iint_{D'}(X+2)dXdY$ where $D': \{X^2+Y^2\leq4\}$.

Comment: So, we shift in that way the axes, so that the circle has as center the origin, right? Why is it necessary that the circle has the center in the origin to calculate the integral?

Comment: Yes, The center of circle goes to origin. I don't think it is necessary as I've done in post!.

Comment: I got it!! Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

OFC your area of $\theta$ has to be restricted to the area where it "hits" the circle and as you already figured out your ansatz leads you to a very complicated calculation.

The reason is that your circle is not centered so first shift your integration area that you have a centered circle by substituting $\overline{x} = x-2, \overline{y} = y-3$ so you get $$\iint_D x dxdy = \iint_\overline{D} (\overline{x} + 2)\;d\overline{x}d\overline{y}$$ with $$\overline{D} =\{(\overline{x},\overline{y})\mid \overline{x}^2+\overline{y}^2\leq 4\}$$

What can easily be solved by using polar coordinates.

Comment: So, we first move the circle so that its center is the origin, right? I haven't I understood that correctly? When we have a circle with center $(x_0, y_0)$ and we want to move it so that the center is the origin, we substitute $\overline{x}=x-x_0$ and $\overline{y}=y-y_0$, right? Why is it easier to calculate the integral when the circle has its center at the origin?

Comment: Because then you don't have to do all your calculations. For a circle on the center your integration bounds are the radius of the circle for r and zero to $2\pi$ for the angle.

Comment: When we have a circle with center other than the origin, then is the radius dependent from the angle? Which would be in that case the angle, not from $0$ to $2\pi$ ?

Comment: Ofc not the radius of the circle but the $r$ as an integration variable depends of it ofc… make a sketch, that helps.
e.g. take a circle with the radius $1$ with the center $(1,1)$. Obviously your integration domain for $\theta$ then is $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ (the whole first quadrant) and e.g. for $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ it has to hold $r\in \left(\sqrt{2}-1,\sqrt{2}+1\right)$ for $r\sin\theta$ and $r\cos\theta$ being in the circle.

Comment: I see!! Thank you!! :-)